# How to paginate query results in NoSQL databases when there are no unique fields included in the projection?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I've heard using MongoDB's skip() to batch query results is a bad idea because it can lead to the server becoming IO bound as it has to 'walk through' all the results. I want to only return a maximum of 200 documents at a time, and then the user will be able to fetch the next 200 if they want (assuming they haven't limited it to less).

Initially I read up on paginating results and most things I read said the easiest way in MongoDB at least is to modify the query criteria to simulate skipping through.

For example if a field called account number on the last document is 28022004, then the next query should have "accNumber > 28022004" in the criteria. But what if there are no unique fields included in the projection? What if the user wants to sort the records by a non-unique field?

Comment: The documentation and research will point to paging through a large number of pages in this way as being a problem. Basically you do not want to "skip" 100,000 documents just to get to the next page. Range queries are preferred but sometimes impossible as you arrive to. The general case is "how deep" are your users going to go? If it is important that they go very deep very often then devise a strategy to efficiently page. Can be quite a broad topic at that point. A few hundred skips are really not going to affect things that much.

Comment: Depending on what technology you use to build your application, you could keep the database cursor in memory and read entries with `next()`.

Comment: What about adding (as the last sort criteria) a sort on the value of ID? For example if the two records where the first 'batch' cuts off both have the same value for the first sort field, then they are sorted by the value of ID? Seeing as ID will always be unique will this work?